# jQuery UI: Drop into relatively positioned container

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI to drag a clone of an object onto a droppable space. However, I need the droppable space to have the `position: relative` property because the droppable space scrolls and I want the dropped elements to scroll with it. However, when I drop the clone it jumps down and to the right instead of staying where I dropped it. How would I combat this?

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nEN7h/42/

EDIT: Updated based on my comment.

Comment: why do you need the droppable space to be `position:relative`? maybe if you jsfiddle me a little more context to your code i can figure it out

Comment: I need to be able to scroll the canvas and have the dragged elements scroll with the canvas. I think this update demonstrates my need for position relative: http://jsfiddle.net/nEN7h/42/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$(".canvas").droppable({
    accept: '.to_drag',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var clone = $(ui.helper).clone();
        var parent = $('.canvas.ui-droppable');

        $(this).append(clone);
        var leftAdjust = clone.position().left - parent.offset().left;
        var topAdjust = clone.position().top - parent.offset().top;
        clone.css({left: leftAdjust, top: topAdjust});

    }
});
```

basically the idea is that when you enclose the droppable inside a div that is relative.. any element enclosed within droppable gets the offset position of the parent unnecessarily added to it.. so you simply remove the extra offset at the drop call back function.

Please pay close attention to difference between [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/).. that is key to understanding the above code.

**note:**
I tried using jsfiddle.. but jsfiddle fiddles a bit with the positioning.. try it on your browser alone and it should work

Comment: My pleasure! I'm glad you put the wider example.. It helped me help you :)

Comment: @abbood  Hi, please anyone ans to my question please click on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/q/40791938/7144629

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution but I'm not sure, if it is that, what you're looking for.

Replace this line:

```
$(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
```

with this one:

```
$('<div class="to_drag"></div>').appendTo(this);
```

If you don't use the ui.helper it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't seen your second Fiddle and I thought my code wouldn't work on this.
But I tried it on the new one and it works, too.

Comment: the problem with that code is that the element jumps to the top left corner of the container, so it is a similar issue.