# Make div expandable when I drop an image on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rGUma/135/), here I can drag and drop images on `.drop-zone` but I want to improve it such that if I drag image on it, the .drop-zone div expands to the position where I am putting the image. Scrollable would be fine.

```
<div class="drag"><img src="http://www.causingeffect.com/images/made/images/example/cow_50_50_c1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="drag"><img src="http://www.coffeecup.com/images/software/feature-icons/image_editing.png" /></div>
<div class="drag"><img src="http://www.neatimage.com/im/Neat-Image-Logo-64.png" /></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="drop-zone"></div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.drop-zone').droppable({
        accept: '.drag',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
            if (!$clone.is('.inside-drop-zone')) {
                $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-drop-zone').draggable({
                     containment: '.drop-zone'
                }));
            }
        }
    });

    $('.drag').draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.drop-zone{border: 1px solid #9C9898;height:350px;width:400px;margin:0 auto;margin-top: 10px; overflow:auto;}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Please better describe "expands to the position".

Comment: If I want to put image outside `.drop-zone` then drop-zone should expand, it should be scrollable.

Comment: Like I move image to edge of `.drop-zone` and it should start stretching.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to detect those edges. I'm using some child `div`s inside `.drop-zone`. Next problem is that you need `.drop-zone` to have `position: relative` and that messes up the drag/drop library. I applied the fix described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963409/jquery-ui-drop-into-relatively-positioned-container).
Next you find out that `mouseover` no longer propagates through the `.drag` element while dragging it, so you need to make sure `.drop-zone-edge` `div`s are above it, thus the custom `z-index` values. Try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5badA/1/).
Apply the same technique for top, left and right and make `.drop-zone-edge`s transparent.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="drop-zone">
    <div class="drop-zone-edge drop-zone-top"></div>
    <div class="drop-zone-edge drop-zone-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.drag {
  z-index: 100;
}

.drop-zone-edge {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;    
    z-index: 200;
}

.drop-zone-top {
    top: 0;
}

.drop-zone-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var isDown = false;

$(document).mousedown(function() {
    isDown = true;
})
.mouseup(function() {
    isDown = false;
});

$('.drop-zone').droppable({
    accept: '.drag',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
        if (!$clone.is('.inside-drop-zone')) {
            $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-drop-zone').draggable({
                 containment: '.drop-zone'
            }));
        }
        var parent = $('.drop-zone');
        var leftAdjust = $clone.position().left - parent.offset().left;
        var topAdjust = $clone.position().top - parent.offset().top;
        $clone.css({left: leftAdjust, top: topAdjust});
    }
});

$('.drag').draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});

var shouldEnlargeBottom = false;
$('.drop-zone-bottom').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    if(isDown) {
        shouldEnlargeBottom = true;
    }
});

$('.drop-zone-bottom').on('mouseout', function(e) {
    shouldEnlargeBottom = false;
});

function enlarge() {
    if(shouldEnlargeBottom) {
        var newHeight = $('.drop-zone').height() + 3;
        $('.drop-zone').height(newHeight);
    }
}

setInterval(enlarge, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it looks hard to achieve it perfectly.

Comment: Well, the other way would be to compute edge detection by yourself based on pointer position and basic geometry, but it won't be easier. I don't think you'll find a ready made plugin.