# Intricate drag and drop jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, scroll, draggable, droppable

**Update:**
Here is the final fiddle. Thanks Twisty.
https://jsfiddle.net/natjkern/55n1Lg61/14/

Here is a mock up of my site
http://jsfiddle.net/natjkern/pjq9wqLy/

On the right I have a fixed list of elements called `#userList`. This element must be set to overflow: auto, as the number of user elements is variable. I then need to drag a copy into dropzone, which again can vary in size, so it's container must be also set to overflow auto. I need the container to auto scroll when dragged element is dragged to edge to allow user to place element anywhere in dropzone. So far my best idea is to append to body first to escape the original auto overflow container then append to `#dropzone` on `droppable({over:})`. But this isn't really working out. Any UI experts out there that can give me a hand?
Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.moveMe').draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        appendTo: 'body',
        revert: 'invalid',
        scroll: true,

    });
    $('#dropZone').droppable({
        accept: '.moveMe',
        //here is where my problem arrises
        // I need #dropZoneCon to scroll to place 

        over: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
            $('#DropZone div').css('position','absolute');
            ui.helper.draggable.draggable('option', 'containment', 'parent');
        },
    /*    */
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
            $('#DropZone div').css('position','absolute');
            ui.helper.draggable.draggable('option', 'containment', 'parent');
        },
    });
});
```

**Note:** commenting out over: allow me to place element where I would like, but I really need the scrolling to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your `over` function, I get the following error: *ui.helper.draggable.detach is not a function*

Comment: In your `over` and `drop` functions, you should call `ui.draggable` not `ui.helper.draggable`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little clunky, but it does what you're looking to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/55n1Lg61/5/

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tEntered = false;
  $('.moveMe').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: 'body',
    revert: 'invalid',
    drag: function(e, u) {
      var curPos = u.offset;
      var $target = $("#dropZoneCon");
      var tVP = $target.offset();
      var tW = Math.floor($target.width());
      var tH = Math.floor($target.height());
      var pad = 20;
      var scrInc = 10;
      var x0 = tVP.top;
      var x1 = tVP.top + tH;
      var y0 = tVP.left;
      var y1 = tVP.left + tW;
      $("#dragInfo").html("Over #dropZone: " + tEntered + ", top: " +
        tVP.top + "/" + curPos.top + "/" + x1 + " left: " + tVP.left + "/" + curPos.left + "/" + y1);
      if (tEntered) {
        // Increase Scroll
        if (curPos.left >= (y1 - pad) && curPos.left <= y1) {
          $target.scrollLeft($target.scrollLeft() + scrInc);
        }
        if (curPos.top >= (x1 - pad) && curPos.top <= x1) {
          $target.scrollTop($target.scrollTop() + scrInc);
        }
        // Decrease Scroll
        if (curPos.left >= y0 && curPos.left <= (y0 + pad)) {
          $target.scrollLeft($target.scrollLeft() - scrInc);
        }
        if (curPos.top >= x0 && curPos.top <= (x0 + pad)) {
          $target.scrollTop($target.scrollTop() - scrInc);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $('#dropZone').droppable({
    accept: '.moveMe',
    over: function(e, u) {
      tEntered = true;
    },
    out: function(e, u) {
      tEntered = false;
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
      $('#DropZone div').css('position', 'absolute');
      ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'containment', 'parent');
    },
  });
});
```

So we do a lot of the heavy lifting in the `drag` event since we can determine the position of the drag object from this event. In the drag event we define a number of variables:

- `curPos` the current position of our draggable object in `{ top, left }`
- `$target` the dropZone container
- `tVP` the Target View Port offset in `{ top, left }`
- `tW` & `tH` the Target's Width and Height
- `scrInc` a value we will use to increase or decrease the scroll position
- `pad` the amount of pixels to use as the edge detection of `tVP`
- `x0` & `x1` are the `tVP` top edge and bottom edge
- `y0` & `y1` are the `tVP` left edge and right edge

I defined `tEntered` outside of these functions, so I can access it from either draggable or droppable. Since droppable has `over` and `out`, we can use those to change this value.

Now, when `tEntered` is true, meaning we are dragging an object over the target, we look to see if the `x` and `y` might be within our padding. If they are we increase or decrease the scroll position.

I found this helpful: http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/how-detect-area-dropped-inside-a-div-into-another-div/

This should allow you to do what you want unless I misunderstood. Comment if you have questions.

Comment: This gets me very close, thank you so much. I just need to have the elements stay where they are dropped instead appending to the top left of the page. I'll mess with it in the morning. Thanks for all your help. It's very frustrating that you had to basically rebuild another scroll feature on top of IU, even more so that I can't find what is keeping UI from handling this the way I'd like on its own. It's seems liked appending the draggable  should activate the auto scroll feature inside the parent element.

Comment: To do that, when you append them, assign the Top and Left to the Mouse X & Y when you drop them. You'll want to use the scroll offsets I think too.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963409/jquery-ui-drop-into-relatively-positioned-container and my updates here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/55n1Lg61/9/

Comment: Just got them to land where I want them, but the draggable elements change shape when they are dragged towards the right side of #dropZone. This shouldn't be an issue, as I will be defining the size of my draggables before dropping, but is certainly strange behavior. I really appreciate the help, it would have taken me forever to finally sort this out. Here is the updated fiddle if you want to check out the weirdness. https://jsfiddle.net/natjkern/55n1Lg61/12/

Comment: May want to move the code out of jsfiddle and test too. It does seem like the DIV is being warped by some edge detection.